# Upgrading Rails application with Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git

Good day,

I would like to upgrade my rails 2.3 application to rails 3. I would like to know what is the proper or right way to use git to manage the upgrading and continue it on each release of my application.

I've been using git for only pull and push but not on a bigger scale.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are really two questions here. I'll address the first.

**Using Git to help with your upgrade**

I would create a branch to do the upgrade work in.

If you are unfamiliar with branching (and merging) Google will get you far, but here is some instruction... http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Once you have the upgrade branch working and tested you could then merge your branch into master and deploy it to production.

Comment: I have forked the project and continue to upgrade it.

Comment: Cool. Just a side note that a fork is conceptually different than a branch and usually associated with something you do on GitHub, not with Git itself.

Comment: I still need the changes from the main repository while doing the upgrades on my fork. This will let me still get my updates on my main repo.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into branching and merging. The short answer is yes. You can merge from master into your upgrade branch and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

git is a version control system for code. to upgrade your rails application from 2.3 to 3, is really a two step process:

1. make sure your application works for rails 3
2. installing/mapping rails -> rails3

the usage of git would come into play only once you've reconfigured the server, then you'd probably want to `git pull` your project fresh again, of course making any post pull config changes.